# Excel formula to compare datetime stamp with today's date

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I am trying to compare some datetime stamp with yesterday date, so that we can determine whether the datetime stamp is overdue or within 24h.

***Excel formula***
[image]

And here is the formula that i am using:

```
=(IF((A2)<(TODAY()-1),"Overdue","Within 24h"))
```

Apparently, it is always taking "Within 24h" (FALSE) no matter we put any dates. (TEST column)

I tried to truncate the datetime stamp to `dd/MM/yyyy` but it is still not working.
(TEST2 column).

I tried to use below formula, none of them is working.

1. `=(IF(INT(A2)<(TODAY()-1),"Overdue","Within 24h"))` ==> Result "#VALUE!"
2. `=(IF(DATEVALUE(A2)<(TODAY()-1),"Overdue","Within 24h"))`
   ==> Result "#VALUE!"

Comment: I think Column A values are string instead of true dates.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I found the culprit.
Apparently, it was due to "Windows Setting => date, time & regional formatting".

Initially, my computer date format was using "mm/dd/yyyy" i.e. "10/27/2021".
And none of these formula were working:

1. `=IF(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(":?? ",A2)+2)) < TODAY()-1,"Over","OK")`
2. `=(IF(INT(B2)<(TODAY()-1),"Overdue","Within 24h"))`
3. `=(IF(DATEVALUE(B2)<(TODAY()-1),"Overdue","Within 24h"))`

After I changed the date format into "dd/mm/yyyy" and restart my computer.
Suddenly all of those formula are working since (in my opinion) the excel is able to recognize column A as a text.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say those left-aligned dates in your cells look mighty suspicious. Are you certain they're not formatted as text?

If they are text, then you'll need to convert them to a date. You're close with your last formula, but those seconds/milliseconds (if that's what they are) are causing the `DATEVALUE()` function to fail.

The easiest thing would probably be to strip out those seconds/milliseconds and do your date compare against the resulting string. Assuming the date as text is in cell A1, the formula would be:

```
=IF(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(":?? ",A1)+2)) < TODAY()-1,"Over","OK")
```